# LinkedIn API product for analysing trends on social media compnany posts

Tags: linkedin-api, social-media

As part of a trend analysis, we are looking for a suitable and legally compliant LinkedIn API product (e.g. at https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog) to evaluate posts and buzzwords based on linkedin company profiles.

Required linkedin fields:

- postUrl
- type
- postContent
- likeCount
- commentCount
- profileURL
- postTimestamp

Is there a suitable official LinkedIn API product that provides posts by timestamp based on a LinkedIn company URL that we can use for further aggregation and reporting?